# Selecting active and hover in one declaration?

Tags: css

Hey guys how can I select :active and :hover pseudo classes in one declaration or is this not possible?

Here's what I have:

```
.hover-listing-btn:hover {
    color:#fff;
}

.hover-listing-btn:active {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Can I shorten that to one declaration?

I am using Bootstrap and it seems like that is quite a lot of CSS just for the sake of changing two selectors.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate both css declaration by a comma. It is not one declaration but at least you have only one css definition body

```
.hover-listing-btn:hover, .hover-listing-btn:active {
    color:#fff;
}
```